# Can echo to file but not putty terminal from bash script invoked from rc.local

Tags: linux, bash, echo, raspbian

I'm a newby, but have spent a few hours trying to figure things out. If I run this script from the command line in PuTTy, it works fine, writing to the file mytest and to the terminal. If it's started by /etc/rc.local after a reboot nothing is written to the terminal, but mytest is still written to. In rc.local I added the following line at the bottom just before exit 0. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
bash /home/pi/mytest.sh &
```

```
#!/bin/bash
cntr="0";
while true
do
        sleep 0.1;
        cntr=$((cntr+1));
        if (("$cntr" == 50)); then
            echo "mytest.sh script is running" > /home/pi/mytest
            echo "mytest.sh script is running"
            cntr=0;
        fi
done
```

Comment: @Charles Duffy, I think I have something close to an MRE. I also added info regarding rc.local.

Comment: Does `journalctl` (or `journalctl | fgrep running`) output the string you are echo-ing?

Comment: Another thought: on some distributions `rc.local` gets ignored unless it's explicitly made executable... is anything **else** in rc.local being run?

Comment: @tink `rc.local` is executed here since the redirection to the file is working. I'm quite certain that the underlying init system redirects standard output to a log file instead of outputting it to the terminal.

Comment: That you're running this from `rc.local` is a critical detail, enough so that it really should be part of the question title -- if you started your program in PuTTY then it inherits the connection to PuTTY from its parent process. If it's started by rc.local, it goes to wherever your distro's scripts have stdout pointed to at that point in the boot process. That's a decision made by your distro (in this case, raspian), not by bash.

Comment: ...because you only start your PuTTY connection _after_ your init scripts have been able to start (after all, those init scripts are what invoked sshd!), it's impossible for them to inherit a stdout that goes to your copy of PuTTY from their parent, because sshd _wasn't running yet_ when that parent process started.

Comment: Charles Duffy gave the Why it didn't work and xhienne is right about the redirection. In my case raspbian (Buster) sent the output to /var/log/syslog.